# Google Apps Script Bug - pulling old data - not pulling the current data in the sheet - Google Sheets caching issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have experienced a case where a Google Apps Script that moves data from one Google Sheet to another Google Sheet, is not pulling the current data in the sheet. I can verify this by checking the Version History in both sheets.

The issue occurred when the script ran from Google Trigger. Though I could not replicate when forcing the script.

I recorded a video to explain the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HChy4WOR5ehg8EA6rlmvSH7Lqjg9bd30/view?usp=drivesdk

As the issue of "pulling old data", is only occurring on ~50 rows. And these are all items that we recently edited. So, that tells me that instead of pulling the "current data" in the sheet, Google pulled some "cached version of the data" instead (i.e. data from a few days, or week before).

I also experienced the same type of old data / caching issue with "IMPORTRANGE" formulas last week. Though this is first instance I have encountered the issue from a script.

This problem has me very worried, as I have setup many business systems to run on Google Sheets and Google Apps Script and rely GAS scripts moving the current/up to date data... for obvious reasons.

I am business owner, not a developer - but I would bet that Google has changed something in recent weeks relating to 'caching of data in Google Sheets'. I have tried reaching out to Google Workplace support to raise this issue but they don't seem to care, and they don't offer any support for GAS.

Hopefully others have this issue and we can get Google to resolve. In the meantime, I have to start preparing for a move away from the unreliable GAS and Google Sheets. Airtable is what I will be looking at firstly.

Comment: Try opening a window in incognito mode. What version does it appear. I'd also try using the [`API explorer` to read the values of the spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%22YOUR_ID%22%2C%22range%22%3A%22%27Mixed%20Data%27!A7223%3A7223%22%2C%22dateTimeRenderOption%22%3A%22FORMATTED_STRING%22%2C%22majorDimension%22%3A%22ROWS%22%2C%22valueRenderOption%22%3A%22FORMATTED_VALUE%22%7D) as the API sees it. Also, this could be an error on the code (we can't tell).

Comment: incognito mode: the latest version is shown
API Explorer:  shows the data as per the latest version

Definitely not an error in the code -- we have used the exact same code for the last 4 years, over about a 100 different versions of the same script. Never had such an issue.

Comment: Suddenly we have these issues only starting ~3 weeks ago. There is 1 script where it has now happened twice in 3 days. Now, I created a simple of the script and see if the copy has the issue when the other one does. Note, that whenever running the script manually it always brings in the current data.

Comment: I'd bet $1,000,000 it's some caching related bug with Google Sheets -- but Google don't seem to care! Nore does anyone else..... anyway if considering to use Google Sheets and rely on Importrange and GAS scripts for your business --- think again!!! I'd recommended AirTable instead.. might actually get acknowledgment of bugs over there

Comment: If you have a Workspace account I'd contact [Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213). Also, you could try [creating a bug report in Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905) but if you don't have a way of reliably reproducing it, they may not be able to help.

Comment: Continue to notice the same issue of "old data" suddenly appearing in sheets using Importrange formulas. Of course, there is NEVER anyway to reliably reproduce the error. I can record videos such as my first video that show the issue occurring in live scenario. But no way to reproduce the issue at will...

Comment: I have now recorded a video showing Version History of 2 Google Sheets to clearly show evidence of this issue. Basically the same as my first video but where the data is updated via Importrange and not a script (hence, cannot be anything with GAS code or API). This is clear evidence this issue does exist. I have posted in 2 other places that may get more exposure then here:

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192809328

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/116022134/importrange-formula-importing-old-stale-data?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this same issue with a script of mine. It pulls cached data for about 4 minutes, then updates to the live version, then repeats that for the next few runs.
For my script in particular, I solved it based on an answer I received here: [Script Pulling Cached Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74165113/google-script-pulling-cached-data/74166260#74166260). I set the text value "Running" to an empty cell on the source sheet at the start of the script, then flush, then delete that value from the dummy cell at the end of the script. Forcing it to write to the source tab seems to force the script to pull live data. It's been working consistently for a few hours now, so I believe this is a viable solution.
I hope this helps!